# Get flex children not to stretch (but inside an absolute parent)?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, alignment

How can I stop `<li>` elements from stretching to fill the height of its flex container? I just want the background to stretch and the items to sit at the top of the box.

I know normally you would use `align-items: flex-start`, but this fails to work as the parent `div` is absolutely positioned.

I will need to retain absolute positioning for part of the layout that is unrelated to this question.

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

ul {
  align-items: flex-start;
  background: gold;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

li {
  flex-basis: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div>
<h1>hello</h1>
<ul>
<li>Test</li>
<li>Test</li>
<li>Test</li>
<li>Test</li>
<li>Test</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Remove `flex-grow:1` from the `ul` if you don't want it to stretch? Nothing to do with positioning at all.

Comment: I need the item to grow to fill the rest of the height of the page (for the gold background).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `align-content: flex-start` to the `ul` (to align *flex line* when you *wrap* a flexbox, you should use the `align-content` property) - see demo below:

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

ul {
  align-items: flex-start;
  background: gold;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-grow: 1;
  align-content: flex-start; /* added */
}

li {
  flex-basis: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div>
<h1>hello</h1>
<ul>
<li>Test</li>
<li>Test</li>
<li>Test</li>
<li>Test</li>
<li>Test</li>
</ul>
</div>
```